# Faceted search with categories using Low Search

Tags: categories, low-search

So I am trying to set up a faceted search which is based on categories - but EE's default category parameters aren't clever enough for me with just the `&` or `|` separators, so I was wondering if I could do what I need to with Low Search.

I have 5 category groups: Age, Artists, Type, Medium and Topic. In each of these is an unknown number of categories. I am displaying checkboxes on the front end for each category group, and have entries assigned to at least 1 category in each group. Here is my list of filters so you can see the options:

[image]

The default view when nothing is ticked is all entries. If I tick 'Multiple' I want all entries categorised with 'Multiple' to show. When I have 'Multiple' and '8-10' ticked I would like everything categorised as both 'Multiple' **and** '8-10' to show. So far so easy - but here is where EE's default breaks:

I tick 'Multiple', '8-10' and '11-14' I want to show everything that is categorised as 'Multiple' **and** '8-10' **or** 'Multiple' **and** '11-14'.

I hope this makes sense and isn't too long winded - ask if something isn't clear and I'll try to clarify. Does anyone know if this is possible with Low Search, and if not - how might I go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, that would be a job for [the Categories filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#categories).

For each group of categories, use a `category:group_name` parameter name to combine AND and OR matching. For example:

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" style="linear"}
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category:group1[]" value="{category_id}"
    {if category_id IN ({low_search_category:group1})} checked="checked"{/if} />
    {category_name}
  </label>
{/exp:channel:categories}

{exp:channel:categories category_group="2" style="linear"}
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category:group2[]" value="{category_id}"
    {if category_id IN ({low_search_category:group2})} checked="checked"{/if} />
    {category_name}
  </label>
{/exp:channel:categories}

...
```

And repeat for each other category group. Note: this code should be put inside the [Form tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#form-tag).

Comment: Thanks Low, this works really well as far as I can tell so far! I have it working with the user physically submitting the form themselves, however in its first iteration (using EE native categories) I had it working with Ajax. Form is on a page - results as an embed on that page. Ajax submits the categories to the embed when user clicks a checkbox and results update after each checkbox click. Do you know if this is possible to achieve with Low Search? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi again Low, don't worry about the Ajax thing. I found your Gist here https://gist.github.com/low/4632695 which explains how to do it nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If hitting "Unexpected ‘IN’ (VARIABLE); expected RD in Template" error in EE 2.9.2 try swapping conditional from

```
{if category_id IN ({low_search_category:group2})} checked="checked"{/if} />
```

to

```
{if category_id ~ '/(^|\|)'.low_search_category:group2.'($|\|)/'} checked="checked" {/if}
```